# enter seperated values to a list of class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to store values into array of class points put when I try to enter the values it take the last value for all of them.  I want each one with diffrent values.

```
class points:
    x=None
    y=None

    list=[points for i in range(y)] list[0].x=0 list[0].y=0 list[1].x=1
    list[1].y=1 list[2].x=2 list[2].y=2

    for i in range(3):
        print(list[i].x)
```

I expected the output to `enter code here` `0 1 2` 
put I get `2 2 2`

Comment: `[points for i in range(y)]` that's several times the same reference of a _class_ in a list comprehension...

Comment: please format your code properly (ctrl+K)

Comment: Please read a tutorial about how to correctly write and use classes in python.

Comment: Also do not use `list` as a name variable. `list` is a built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to write what you want to achieve.

```
class points:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=None
        self.y=None
```

The `__init__()` special method allows you to initialize an instance of a class.

```
mylist = [points() for _ in range(3)]
```

Pay attention to the round brackets after `points`. They say to instantiate an instance of the class: the `__init__()` method defined before is called. Otherwise is just a reference to the class.
Also do not use `list` as a variable name, is a built-in function.

```
mylist[0].x=0
mylist[0].y=0
mylist[1].x=1
mylist[1].y=1
mylist[2].x=2
mylist[2].y=2
 
for i in range(3):
    print(mylist[i].x)
```

This prints what you expect.

#### EDIT

As pointed out in the comment, to avoid the six lines of attribute initialization, the class can be written as:

```
class points:
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        self.x=a
        self.y=b
```

and then:

```
mylist = [points(i, i) for i in range(3)]
```

Now all the points instances in `mylist` are initialized with the same values.

Comment: You could just pass the x, y to the point constructor when you make the point. then you don't need the extra 6 lines to assign data. Good explanation for a beginner though.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse yeah, you are right. I usually try to stay the closest possible to the OP code, I feel will be easier to understand the answer. But in this case is worth to add that part too. I'll edit the answer